# Filezilla fail to connect Dropbear SSH server _ unexpected end-of-file

Tags: ssh, nat, sftp, alpine, dropbear

I install **dropbear** SSH server in **Alpine** OS
dropbear config :

```
DROPBEAR_OPTS=" -p 22 -K 9"
```

( p = port , K = keep-alive in seconds)
now I can connect to SSH terminal in **KVM**

```
ssh root@192.168.122.58
```

but I **can not** connect to server via **SFTP**
Filezilla **debug level** set to **3-Verbose** an output :

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.122.58...
    Trace:  Going to execute /usr/bin/fzsftp
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse(fzSftp started, protocol_version=8)
    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
Command:    open "root@192.168.122.58" 22
    Trace:  Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_2019.78
    Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
    Trace:  Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
    Trace:  Server also has ssh-dss/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
    Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
    Trace:  ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 1c:c4:21:fb:3e:c6:a9:8e:48:5b:e3:b3:5e:ce:f8:e7 qZSD38O3128ChhxwkWGNXWdofKwQs6g3nWmxxHm5IcU=
    Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
    Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
    Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
    Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
    Trace:  Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
    Trace:  Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
Command:    Pass: ****
    Trace:  Sent password
    Trace:  Access granted
    Trace:  Opening session as main channel
    Trace:  Opened main channel
    Trace:  Started a shell/command
Status: Connected to 192.168.122.58
Error:  Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server <------------- HERE
    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::OnTerminate without error
    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: i aslo remove dropbear config > `DROPBEAR_OPTS=""` but same error occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbear doesn't include the sftp daemon. You need to install that also.

I don't use Alpine, but a google search makes it look like the package you would need would be called `openssh-sftp-server`.

Comment: really thanks , it works fine now